# Mapping file data to environment variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-system, bluemix

This is a follow-on to my previous question: [Enforcing set environment variables](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/97826/enforcing-set-environment-variables)

While learning more about JavaScript, node, and the bluemix environment, I have been using the loading of process environment variables as a starting point for understanding how the systems work.

This part of the system checks to see if a 'default' value exists for an environment variable. If there is a default, and the variable is not set, then the variable is set to the default's value. Default values are stored in a file in a pre-defined directory (the same folder as the script file).

After taking in the review suggestions, and some other suggestions from colleagues, I have changed the code mechanism to use a map/filter/process system on the files. This makes the code quite a bit neater.

Note: this code is a file/module in a node.js application deployed in a Bluemix host.

Again I am looking for any further insights in to how the code can be improved, and if any edge cases exist. Performance is not critical, but as I am just learning JavaScript I would appreciate any insights in to any bad practices that should be avoided so that issues are avoided later on.

In particular, I am concerned that the code is not as asynchronous as it could be, though it is a requirement that all the variables are set before the code terminates (nothing asynchronous can be incomplete).

```
/*jshint node:true*/

/*
 * Load various pre-determined environment variables
 * (files in this folder with .env extension).
 * Only if they have not previously been set in the environment.
 * 
 * This makes the setting of Bluemix style variables quite easy.
 */

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var env = /\.env$/;

function isEnv(fileName) {
    return fileName.match(env);
}

function processEnv(fileName) {
    var key = fileName.replace(env, "");
    if (process.env.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        return;
    }
    var filePath = path.join(__dirname, fileName);
    var data = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
    process.env[key] = data;
}

fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter(isEnv)
    .forEach(processEnv);
```

Comment: Instead of re-inventing the wheel, might I suggest `dotenv`, the npm package? It effectively takes everything in the `.env` file in the cwd and sets it to environment variables. Posting this in a comment because you might *want* to reinvent the wheel. https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: @DanPantry - I was not intending to reinvent the wheel. dotenv looks like it should be what I am using, but it does not have the same functionality. I will probably rename my file extensions to something other than `.env` to avoid confustion... but, for example, I need to set `VCAP_SERVICES` to large strings like [this example](http://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html#VCAP-SERVICES)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is very clean and is definitely a clear improvement from your last version.

Your code is easy to understand and follow, now that's it's more broken up (aside from one big block of code).

---

I recommend storing your regexular expression for locating the extension `.env` like this:

```
var env = new RegExp("\.env$/", "");
```

The reason is for this: `RegExp.test`.

The `test` method of a `RegExp` object does the following:

- Returns `true` if the regexular expression matches the input string.
- Returns `false` if the regexular expression *does not* match the input string.

Now, your `isEnv` function does this:

```
return env.test(fileName);
```

Why is this better? Well...

- The `test` method of `RegExp` only has to worry about the regexular expression matching at all.
- The `match` method of a string has to worry about the regexular expression matching AND it has to worry about creating and returning an array of all the matches.

That being said, the `test` method is obviously faster than using `match`.